# Angular 2: Assign math statement to variable in template?

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 template, I have an extremely cumbersome calculation in the form of:

```
<td class="text-right"><strong>
                    {{((avgGrossProfitPer * addMonthlySalesVolume) + (addMonthlySalesVolume * addCarryingCostProf / 100) + 
                    (accessAmount + 10 + numChecks + (addMonthlySalesVolume * 0.075)) || '0') | currency:'USD':true}}
                    </strong>
                </td>
```

All the variables here were set by `input [(ngModel)]="templateName"`. However, what I would like to do is set the value of this calculation to a variable so I don't have to copy/paste this whole formula again.

What I've tried is:

```
<td class="text-right"><strong #monthlyroi>
                    {{((avgGrossProfitPer * addMonthlySalesVolume) + (addMonthlySalesVolume * addCarryingCostProf / 100) + 
                    (accessAmount + 10 + numChecks + (addMonthlySalesVolume * 0.075)) || '0') | currency:'USD':true}}
                    </strong>
                </td>

<!--Try to return the value of the calculation above-->
<span>{{monthlyroi}}</span>
```

However, `{{monthlyroi}}` returns "[object HTMLElement]" when rendered on the page.

Comment: have you considered just putting a function accepts the parameters you need and that returns the value you want between the double curly braces?

Comment: I have, though I'm new to Angular 2 so not sure what the best way to approach this would be. I tried writing a function in `app.component.ts` that accepted those values as parameters, but I wanted the value to automatically update every time the user changed an input, so I just had lots of `(keyup)="functionName(myparamaters)"` everywhere in my template, which seemed to make things clunky.

Comment: Instead, you can use `(change)=...` instead of `(keyup)=...`

Comment: Because monthlyroi is a element reference not a variable

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can refer to all these variables means that they are members of your component. That means that you can just encapsulate the complicated calculation in a method

In your component,

```
export class MyComponent {
 .......

  myFancyCalculation(): number {
    return ((this.avgGrossProfitPer * this.addMonthlySalesVolume) +
            (this.addMonthlySalesVolume * this.addCarryingCostProf / 100) +
            (this.accessAmount + 10 + this.numChecks + (this.addMonthlySalesVolume * 0.075)) || '0')
  }
}
```

And now you can use `myFancyCalculation()` in your template  (appropriately named, of course).

The reason for choosing a method rather than a variable is that with a variable, you have to manually keep updating that calculated variable as the various input variables change. By using a function instead, you no longer have to do that manual synchronization.

FYI, considering the size of that calculation, i'd probably create some helper methods to better encapsulate and describe what the calculation is doing.

**EDIT:**

You can add the variables in the calculation as member variables of MyComponent

eg: 
    export class MyComponent {
       .......
       avgGrossProfitPer: number;
       addMonthlySalesVolume: number;
       etc...

Doing the above will allow you to access the variables in the myFancyCalculation method.

The second option is to change myFancyCalculation to accept the various fields as parameters. In that case, in the myFancyCalculation, you won't prefix the variables with `this.` since they will just be parameters to your method

eg.
    myFancyCalculation(avgGrossProfit: number, addMonthlySalesVolume: number  ...etc )

And in your template,

```
<td class="text-right">
     <strong>
                {{ myFancyCalculation(avgGrossProfitPer, addMonthlySalesVolume ... etc) }}
     </strong>
```

Comment: What I need to do though is have this calculation called each time one of my variables' value is changed. So would I have to add `(change)="myFancyCalculation()"` to every `input` where my variables are defined?

Comment: You mentioned that the various variables used in the calculation are bound to input fields using ngModel right?   If so, then ngModel will update the individual variable values as the user types in the inputs, and then Angular's change detection will update your calculation in the view. You won't have to add a separate (change) binding.  That's assuming you're using ngModel on the individual variables

Comment: When I write the function you provided in `app.component.ts`, I get the error: `Property 'variableName' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.` for all my variables. I'm not sure how to make them "exist" in this context, when I have them set in `app.compoment.html` with `<input [(ngModel)]="variableName">`

Comment: In your app.component.ts,  you'll have to add them there as member variables. The other option is to pass all the variables as parameters to myFancyCalculation(). I'll update the code with examples